# Stop a workflow when the item is deleted

Tags: 2010, list, workflow, custom-list

I have a workflow that waits for a certain date to occur depending on the user input. However when the list item is deleted, the workflow still runs.

Is there a way to say

```
Wait for item to be deleted
Then Stop the Workflow
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. You can follow below pattern to solve the issue

```
Store currentitem id to a workflow variable WV_ID

Wait for X timeframe

If list not contains item with ID = WV_ID   
    Current Item is deleted - Log Message & Stop Workflow
Else
    ... Continue normal operations
```